# ASP.NET database connection string error of AttachDBFilename property

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to set the `AttachDBFilename` property of connection string in `Web.config`, with the absolute path of the `mdf` file, it works, I want to use `|DataDirectory|` instead of the absolute path, here is what I tried, but it does work.

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , try to check if there is a `log file` under the same directory with your `mdf` file, if there is, remove the `log file`, Once the database is attached, a new log file will be automatically generated based on the physical path.